# google-drive can't get push notifications

Tags: node.js, push-notification, google-drive-api

I can't get push notifications, after editing files in google drive.
Used libraries: **googleapis**, **google-auth-library**.
There is channel:

```
drive.changes.watch({
    pageToken: tokenId,
    resource: {
        id: uuid.v1(),
        type: 'web_hook',
        address: 'https://7def94f6.ngrok.io/notifications'
    }
}, function(err, result, message) {
    console.log(err, result);    
});
```

The result in terminal

[image]

When I try to use "Try it!" in google-drive api

[I get this error (on screenshot you can see my parameters)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNkLv.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HE he, as I told you before i don't know anything about Drive api. But I think i got this. Look in your `console log` that you inserted above. You have smth called:

```
Start Token: 6178
```

Then on the filed you have the error it says:

"This (box) should be set to a value of the nextPageToken `from the previous response` or `form the getStartPageToken method` (string)"

What i do not get form your question, is where do you got your `2234 Token` that you want to put in that box? I guess you are using the nextPageToken method? But still assuming that the system starts form scratch, you do not have any "`previous response`" => so you can't have another token in that box, but the `start token` from console..

So for now, my suggestion is instead `2234` put the start token: `6178`.

Note: I could be dead wrong about this. Because this question implies another question, it should be a comment but i don't have enough experience to add one. Hope that helped you somehow.

Comment: Thanks, Alon! I think some thing wrong with my params.

Comment: Thanks, Alon! Your post helped me. I had bug with tokens.